# How to integrate dlmalloc in a Windows Phone 8 c++/cli application

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, malloc

I'm attempting to integrate dough lea's malloc (malloc.c) into a native WP8 app.

Adding the dlmalloc.c file to the **MVS 2012 for Windows Phone** results in a "cannot compile malloc.c with the /ZW option" error. Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304862/d8048-cannot-compile-c-file-openssl-applink-c-with-zw-option) I got rid of that problem.

Then I got rid of the EINVAL and ENOMEM undefined errors by including errno.h at the start of malloc.c

But now I'm stuck with different variations of:

> error C2375: 'malloc': redefinition; different linkage (in file stdlib.h)

(for malloc, calloc, free and realloc)

I tried setting the NO_MALLOC_STATS for the dlmalloc to stop the include of stdlib.h but that didn't seem to solve it, as well as #undef-ing calloc.

Has anyone tried integrating dlmalloc in a wp8 app? If so, am I going the right way about it?

Thanks,

Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the last step missing was adding

> "#define USE_DL_PREFIX"

At the top of the file, to use the dlmalloc, dlfree,... names instead of malloc, free, and so on.

Once that was done, I was able to use dlmalloc and the rest in my code.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. There was a typo. It should be USE_DL_PREFIX not USE_DEL_PREFIX.